# Pairwise testing: How to create the table from a text file?

Tags: algorithm, testing, text-files

I have a question regarding how to create the table for the pairwise testing. For example, if I have a table with a list of words (each line contains a single word).

E.g.text file contains:

```
red
blood 
animal
```

How do I create a table of input with all possible combination then? Would it look something like this? It gets the line number of word and creates all possible outputs. 
I want an output something like this:

```
| 0 1 2
 -----------
  0 | 0 10 11
  1 | 10 0 21
  2 | 11 12 0
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear, what is the exactly the interpretation of row i and column j. Can explain more clearly why table(1, 2) = 21 or table(0, 2) = 11? How are these numbers related to the strings "red", "blood", and "animal"?

Comment: @A.Mashreghi In the text, I mentioned that it gets the list and assigned a number to each row  (red =0, blood=1 and animal= 2).

Comment: Your resulting table is nothing to do with pairwise. It is cartesian product which is all possible combinations of input values